# Latency of a unix send() call with TCP_NODELAY

Tags: unix, send

What is the expected latency of send() when used with TCP_NODELAY option? From our tests this was around 2.5us for 10G network. Does this mean it will take 2.5us in tcpstack?

If IO non-blocking mode is used with tcp_nodelay will the send() latency be much lower than 2.5us as it's supposed to be mem copy?

Comment: I think the answer to this question will totally depend on what OS and what hardware, and what software is involved.  There is nothing in the TCP protocol that specifies latency; in fact one of the big features of TCP is its ability to work across hardware of widely varying performance.  I wouldn't expect there to be much difference in latency between blocking and non-blocking modes, though, unless you are trying to handle multiple sockets from a single thread (in that case, non-blocking IO will perform better as socket B will never have to wait for an operation on socket A to complete, etc).

Comment: Non-blocking mode has nothing to do with latency. It is simply a flag set ahead of time on a socket so that individual reads/writes return immediately. When any `read` or `write` is not able to be completed, an appropriate error number such as `EAGAIN` is returned rather than causing the entire server to wait for the operation to complete. Waiting still happens, but in a different way, by using other system calls like `select` or `kqueue` which do "block" but in an efficient way as they monitor progress on lots of connections at once.

Comment: Which means if non blocking mode is used, send should return immediately within few nano-seconds even though tcp_nodelay is used? Btw the latency was tested in RHEL6.2 with connect x3 eth cards.